# Bokeh: Force onclick event to a Legend via JS callback

Tags: bokeh, bokehjs

I'm using Bokeh 2.3.0. I have several items in my Legend that are all muted on load. I provided a button that I want to use for toggling the visibility of all legend items.

Here's what I have now:

[image]

Here's my JS callback:

[image]

I believe I'm close enough to achieve it but setting the *muted* property doesn't work and I don't know how to send an *onclick* event. Hope someone can help or confirm that this is not supported in BokehJS.
[image]

Comment: Where are you expecting the value of `this.origin` to come from and what are you expecting it to be? It does not exist inside the callback function, which is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: @bigreddot `this.origin` refers to the Button. there's no issue inside the callback. the error in my screenshot is using the browser console after the breakpoint is triggered. I believe it is due to improper use of `trigger_event`. can you give a sample usage?

Comment: These aren't really intended to be public API, which is why they are not demonstrated anywhere. I'd regard any usage of `trigger_event` outside BokehJS internals to be improper usage so I don't have any sample to share. Programatic access to hiding/muting legends seems like a reasonable ask. I'd recommend submitting a [github issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) about it. There is either some current reaonable way of doing it that I just don't know about (in which case it needs to be documented better) or there isn't (in which case the issue can be a feature request).

Comment: ok, thanks @bigreddot

Comment: `cb_obj` is the button object, not `this`.